# Prevent C# Dll from being loaded for certain apps

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, dll, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

Greetings all,

I have a shell toolbar extension written in C#.  It's only meant to be used in Windows Explorer, so I want to prevent the DLL from being loaded in Internet Explorer.  Windows provides tons of ways to load extensions in IE only, but seemingly no way to do Explorer only.  I know there are various checks I could perform in different places after the DLL is loaded, but the ideal would be to prevent the DLL from loading at all.

Now, if it were written C++, I would call `GetModuleFileName` in `DllMain`, check if the executable was `iexplore.exe`, and return false on attach if so.  But there is no `DllMain` in C#; Microsoft doesn't trust us to play nice with loader lock.  Is there any other way I can selectively prevent a C# DLL from loading?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do Shell Extension Handlers in .NET
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx

Comment: Not relevant... The reason that advice was given was that doing shell extensions in .NET could cause a CLR injection problem for unmanaged programs that use shell dialogs.  Extensions written in different CLR versions could conflict with each other.  But that's only relevant for things like context menu handlers, or other extensions that could be used in shell dialogs.  Toolbars are only loaded by two applications: Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer.  And not only that, .NET now supports supports in-memory side-by-side operation of multiple CLR versions, so this is completely outdated now.

Comment: I didn't realize it was outdated, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Section 3: Registering our AppBar
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx?print=true

I had to send this one in a separate post as a new user is not allowed to send more than one link in 1 post.

Comment: The link you provided deals with AppBars, which are completely different than Explorer toolbars (formally called DeskBands).  AppBars only load in Explorer, not IE, so they're not really relevant to my problem...

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have been trying to see if I can find a relevant registry key using autoruns that will register an Explorer Toolbar only for Windows Explorer but no luck yet, Does anyone know that there is NO way to use the registry to  register a Explorer Toolbar only for Explorer?